# Return ActiveRecord::Relation from a tableless model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activerecord-relation

In my application (Rails 4), the User model is not stored in the 'local' database but is on a backoffice application.

So, I use a tableless model (with the gem from softace / activerecord-tableless) and I have a module 'ApiUser' to access my backoffice.

The User model (tableless) use this module for every operation (read or write data...) on the backoffice.

In my model I implement a 'all' method (and a corresponding function in the API to retrieve  data from the backoffice).
For the moment, in the model, I create an array populated with data by doing `result[:user].each { |user| users << User.new(user) }` ('result[:user]' is the data retrieved by the module).
It works pretty well but I have relation (has_many) to other models and some automatic functions don't work (`each`, `index_by`, `map`...) on the relation.

My question is : how to simulate an ActiveRecord::Relation like a real ActiveRecord model ?
(maybe with deserialize ? but I didn't find anything helpfull. I also read the RailsCasts 239 about ActiveRecord relation but it didn't help me)

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @moregeek No, I didn't. I changed my program to do another way.